# Yarn shows the jobs is succeeded but the EMR shows the step is still running

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

Yarn shows the jobs is succeeded(in Yarn UI) but the EMR shows the step(in EMR console UI) is still running and it shows like tat forever. Any thought ?
I am writing to s3 as json part files and I see this in driver logs :

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File already exists:s3n:
```

But the driver is still running but yarn shows as successed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, where s3 was telling me that the file already existed and the job was finishing as expected. First of all, don't use `s3n://`, use `s3://` instead, as recommended in [this issue](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-file-system-s3/).

In order to get rid of the `IOException`, I enabled [EMRFS consistent view](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html), which is recommended for "clusters that run quick, sequential steps using Amazon S3 as a data store", which was my case. YMMV.